# Query string not handled from child class

Tags: php, database, oop, authentication

This is my first time here so i hope you can help me. This is my problem:

I'm busy with a log-in script in oop.

I have the following classes ready:

- database class
  this is just an connection/disconnection class
- query class extends the database class
  there is only 1 function and that only takes a query string and get it through the database and eventually returns an array with the data.
- login class
  this class will get user login information and gets user informatie from the database.

this is the folder structure:

```
/
/cgi-bin -> holds the database and query class
/libraries -> holds the login class
```

Then there are 2 files left and they are the index.php and the global.php.

In my index I have this:

```
require_once('global.php');

print_r($login->userCheck('test'));
```

and this is inside my global.php:

```
include('cgi-bin/database.php');
include('cgi-bin/query.php');
include('libraries/login.lib.php');


$login = new Login();
```

this is my login class

```
class Login extends Query{

  public function Login(){

  }

  public function userCheck($userCredentials){
  $result = $this->qString('SELECT * FROM users');
  return $result;

}

}
```

and my query class

```
class Query extends Database{
  function qString($qString){

    //Start connection with database
    $this->conncect();

    $result = $this->db->query($qString);
    // fetch associative array
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }

    // free result set 
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    //Close connection with database
    $this->disconnect();

    //Check mysqli connection
    //print_r(explode('  ', mysqli_stat($this->db)));

    return $data; 

  }
}
```

and the database class:

```
class Database {

  //Private variables for database connection.
  private $server;
  private $usern;
  private $userp;
  private $database;

  //The database object.
  protected $db;

  function Database(){

    $dbCredentials = explode(',',file_get_contents('cgi-bin/dbcredentials.txt'));

    $this->server = $dbCredentials[0];
    $this->usern  = $dbCredentials[1];
    $this->userp  = $dbCredentials[2];
    $this->db     = $dbCredentials[3];

  }

  protected function conncect(){            
    $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->server, $this->usern, $this->userp, $this->db);
  }

  protected function disconnect(){
    mysqli_close($this->db);
  }

}
```

now when I run this it says this:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\cgi-bin\query.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\cgi-bin\query.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\cgi-bin\query.php on line 25
```

Why am I getting this error?

Edit 12-10-2011:

I have found what the error was.

just to share it with you:
There error was that the construct from the database class was never run.

Because of that, the connection details like username and password were never set to the private variables and with that it could never connect.

With the result that the query never could run from the login class.

So it was pretty simple in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for [`mysqli::query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). It returns a result set *only when there are results*. On error, it will return boolean `false`, and for many types of queries it will return a boolean `true` on success:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a MySQLi_Result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You're also not checking the return value of `$this->db->query(...)`. If it is failing and returning `false`, you're blindly passing that **boolean** value to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, hence the error message

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Please add some basic error handling to your code:

```
$result = $this->db->query($qString);

if ($result === false) {
  // error in query
  die("'$query' failed");
}

if ($result === true) {
  // not a query which returns results
  return true;
}

// fetch associative array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer @mellamokb and meagar.
Altough i was a little incomplete in my question.
sorry for that.

But the problem is not the error handeling(although indeed it wasnt there) but the query is 100% correct.

I know this because when i instatiate the query class inside the index en run the query it gives me the correct result.

so ive been thinking te past hour that it has to do with the encapsulation of my variables inside the database and query class.

cant think of something more right now :S

Comment: Your right about the error handeling. I need to put that in there. I also did that and the errors are gone. But still i keep getting no results from the query and thats the problem. im still puzzled about how that can be. so ill be looking further for an answer so if you maybe have an idee for the error than it would be nice

Comment: @Controvi The most important thing you could have told us is still missing: What is the return value of `db->query`? Can you please `var_dump` it? Can you verify which query you're running by also dumping `$qString` before it executes? If you're no longer getting errors but getting empty results, can you verify that your query actually produces results?

Comment: I've tried the var_dump on the incomming query that is past with the parameter. also tried the var dump on the result var but give back false.
it just so weird that after creating an instance for query in the index the `$query->qString('SELECT * FROM users')` it works but when i call the the function from an extended class it fails.

Comment: what i just thought of, is that it could be that the function  class calling the query is a third extend. by that i mean that login.lib.php extends query extends database.
im going to look into that now.

Comment: dont know if you recieve a message when i edit the my main question but just to be sure to let you know what went wrong look in the post above @ the bottom.